# Can I install shared imported library?

Tags: cmake

I have an external project and an imported shared library. The include directories and implib all work correctly, but trying to install the shared library (dll) fails with the following error:

```
install TARGETS given target "my_shared_lib" which does not exist in this directory.
```

Here's code to reproduce:

```
add_library(my_shared_lib SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET my_shared_lib PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProjects/my_shared_lib")
set_property(TARGET my_shared_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProjects/my_shared_lib/my_shared_lib.dll")
set_property(TARGET my_shared_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProjects/my_shared_lib/my_shared_lib.lib")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_dependencies(main my_shared_lib)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC my_shared_lib)

install(TARGETS main DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DIST")
install(TARGETS my_shared_lib DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DIST")
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: For now I've gotten around this problem by using get_property to pull out the IMPORTED_LOCATION, then using INSTALL FILES and giving the value of that property. It seems to work, but is there a better, more idiomatic-cmake solution?

Answer (score 26):

CMake doesn't allow to install *IMPORTED* libraries as *TARGETS*. Use `install(FILES)` instead.

There are at least 2 reasons for such behavior:

1. Сitation of one of CMake developer from [bug report](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14311)

   > Imported targets were originally designed for importing from an existing installation of some external package so installing did not make sense at the time.
2. When install *normal* library, CMake is able to modify it for adjust some properties like RPATH. Such modification is possible because CMake **knows how the library has been built**. This is a main advantage of installing library as a *TARGET*.

   But for *IMPORTED* library CMake has no information about the library's compilation process, and cannot perform any reasonable modification of it. So, CMake may only install the library file **as is**: no advantages against simple `install(FILES)`.

Comment: `rpath` is actually one of the few properties that can be modified in elf binaries quite easily
https://nixos.org/patchelf.html

Comment: install(TARGET) has one useful property not covered here. It also creates the links from <file>.so to <file>.so.<major> and <file>.so.<minor>.<minor> on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 14):

In CMake 3.21, there is a new subcommand to `install(...)` called `IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS`.

See the full [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/install.html#imported-runtime-artifacts).

In your case, you could just do something like this:

```
install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS my_shared_lib)
```

Comment: Thank you, this simplifies things and just keeps it clean and simple. I didn't want the user to have to pass an "install path" nor have to know the name of the generated binary[using add_executable(... IMPORTED...)].