# Problems with rpath in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm having a problem with cmake, like
One of the libraries which I want to link to my shared library which I'm compiling is boost.
So, I tried like:

```
target_link_libraries(my_project
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SIGNALS_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY})
```

However, when I execute in the terminal to check the linkage

```
    ldd libmy_project.so
    libboost_system.so.1.66.0 => not found
    libboost_chrono.so.1.66.0 => not found
    libboost_date_time.so.1.66.0 => not found
    libboost_regex.so.1.66.0 => not found
    libboost_signals.so.1.66.0 => not found
    libboost_thread.so.1.66.0 => not found
```

But the boost library was found by the cmake in the CMakeList.
Anybody know how to fix this?

Edit:

The problem was to set properly the rpath, I tried to follow the cmake documentation. However, it didn't work for me.
The only thing which worked was adding this line before the `target_link_libraries(...)` in CMkaeLists.txt:

```
set_target_properties(YOUR_PROJECT PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath, YOUR_LIB_LOCATION_HERE")
```

Comment: Dynamic loader (`ldd`) uses RPATH mechanism for find libraries. If you have Boost installed not to the *system-default* path, you need to adjust RPATH for find it. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649565/how-to-make-cmake-embed-library-path-of-imported-target-into-executable.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having some problems to ajust the rpath properly, I still can't link that

Comment: `but I'm having some problems to ajust the rpath properly` - Then update the question post with a description of what have you tried.

Comment: What's the version of CMake? It has to be 3.11 or newer, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Comment: `I tried to follow the cmake documentation. However, it didn't work for me.` - Once again, you say you have problem with your code... but show the **other code**, which works. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: @usr1234567: I don't see why CMake version could be a problem. Configure and build steps has been finished successfully (`libmy_project.so` library has been created). And none "Find" script, including one for Boost, definitely does not operate with RPATH.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Whenever I see recent versions of CMake and no CMake version in the question, there is a high chance to help. Without the CMake version number, the question is incomplete. But in detail, you are right.

Comment: I tried with CMake 3.11.1