# How to install a target that link privately against an Interface library

Tags: c++, cmake

Hello developper friends, I'm using CMake for a while now, but I could't figure how to install a target :

- that is part of an export set
- that link privately against interface library

The export set is created with the command

```
install(EXPORT MyExportSet DESTINATION MyExportDir
        NAMESPACE Project FILE ProjectTargets.cmake)
```

the link to the interface library is done like this

```
target_link_libraries(exportedTarget
    PRIVATE interfaceTargetLibrary
)
```

and finally i'm exporting the target like this :

```
install(TARGETS exportedTarget EXPORT MyExportSet
      ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static
      LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
      RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
      INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
```

This look rights to me, and following the logic of the PRIVATE flag uppon linking, I shouldn't have to export the target interfaceTargetLibrary

But CMake throw me an error (This one)

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "ProjectTargets" ...) includes target"exportedTargets" which requires target "interfaceTargetLibrary" that is not in the export set.
```

So here my question, is that a bug ? or something I didn't understand ? And obviously did you achieve to make it work on way or another.

I'm using CMake version 3.7.

EDIT : Finded out, if someone interested. It's because, the library that is linked privately wont be packaged in the one I export. So, the comsummer of the library will need, to link against interfaceTargetLibary
too and so I need to export it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's linked privately, you can use the following trick: [CMake won't try to install an `IMPORTED` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41179630/11107541).

Also see ["What is an `INTERFACE IMPORTED` library in CMake and what are its uses?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023803/11107541).

I tried to find official documentation on this behaviour but I could not. I did find [a related discussion ticket on kitware's repo](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/14311) though.