# install TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS with cmake

Tags: cmake, tbb

I compile TBB with tbb_build command. To allow searching for TBB libraries without adding to the loading path, I want to install the TBB libraries (libtbb.so, libtbbmalloc.so, libtbbmalloc_proxy.so) to a destination folder. I used the command

install(FILES ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS} DESTINATION libs)

However, cmake produce an error at the installation process:

file INSTALL cannot find
  "${application_source_folder}/TBB::tbb".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:84 (include)

Makefile:73: recipe for target 'install' failed

What can be done to tell cmake to install those libraries? As of now I have to manually copy to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

CMake treats target names as filenames in your case. Normally for installing targets you should use `install(TARGETS ...)` instead of `install(FILES ...)`. **But** it does not work for IMPORTED targets (see [Can I install shared imported library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175354/can-i-install-shared-imported-library)).

You can use a workaround: get needed files using `get_target_property` and install using `install(FILES ...)`:

```
# Collect IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE values from all TBB targets
foreach(tbb_target ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
    get_target_property(tbb_lib ${tbb_target} IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
    list(APPEND tbb_libs_to_install ${tbb_lib})
endforeach()

# Install the collected values
install(FILES ${tbb_libs_to_install} DESTINATION libs)
```

You can use other properties to get other files, e.g. for debug versions of TBB libraries use `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` property.