# cmake: install externally supplied include and lib

Tags: c++, build, cmake, installation, cmake-language

I have a very simple problem, which I don't find a solution for:

I'm working with a company that once in a while sends me two directories, one with .h files and the second with a library in two forms, shared and static.
say -

```
X/include/*
X/lib/libX.so
X/lib/libX.a
```

I would like to wrap this input with a cmake project that does this simple action -
create a cmake target that I can install, alias, version, etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you spend some time with the CMake documentation and attempt a solution? Please post the CMake code you have tried already.

Comment: yes, sure, posting in stackoverflow is the last option. Take a look at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html - all requires source files, and the imported one does not allow adding files.

Comment: also, couldn't find a way to naturally install or add dependencies for custom-target .

Comment: Did you look closely at [`IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) libraries? [This](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#sex-drugs-and-imported-targets) is a good introduction.

Comment: @Botje - I read it few times. it is good, but very hard to use as a reference. I'll reread it again, looking for answers

Comment: Note, that CMake doesn't allow to install IMPORTED libraries. Just use `install(FILES)` for install your files. See that question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175354/can-i-install-shared-imported-library/41179630

Comment: @Tsyvarev sure I can install the files, but then I loose the benefit of "target-oriented" cmake. I cannot EXPORT it as a target, I cannot ALIAS it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets) as it's explain pretty well how to import targets.

Something like this should work :

```
# Shared library
add_library(LibX-Shared SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(LibX-Shared PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "X/include"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "X/lib/libX.so"
)

# Static library
add_library(LibX-Static STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(LibX-Static PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "X/include"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "X/lib/libX.a"
)
```

Then you should be able to use these targets in CMake :

```
target_link_libraries(myexe LibX-Shared)
```